# É possível realizar um filtro através de uma coluna calculada?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Senhores(as), estou realizando o seguinte select em minha base de dados.

```sql
SELECT TOP 5 A.APELIDO,
        A.REALIZADO,
        A.META,
        CAST((A.REALIZADO/A.META)*100 AS DECIMAL(10)) AS ACUMULADO,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ((A.REALIZADO/A.META)*100)DESC) AS RANKING

        FROM (

        SELECT

        VEN2.APELIDO,

        ((SELECT ISNULL(SUM((ITE1.QTDNEG*ITE1.VLRUNIT)-ITE1.VLRDESC-ITE1.VLRREPRED),0)
        FROM TGFCAB CAB1 (NOLOCK)
        LEFT JOIN TGFITE   ITE1 (NOLOCK) ON ITE1.NUNOTA=CAB1.NUNOTA 
        LEFT JOIN TGFVEN   VEN1 (NOLOCK) ON VEN1.CODVEND=CAB1.CODVEND
        LEFT JOIN TGFPRO   PRO1 (NOLOCK) ON PRO1.CODPROD = ITE1.CODPROD
        WHERE CAB1.TIPMOV = 'V'
        AND   CONVERT(DATE,CAB1.DTFATUR) BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2019-01-31'
        AND   ITE1.CODCFO IN (5102,5403,5405,5922,6102,6108,6110,6403,6404,6922)
        AND   CAB1.STATUSNFE <> 'D'
        AND   PRO1.MARCA = 'SAMSUNG'
        AND   PRO1.CODGRUPOPROD = 1001001
        AND   VEN1.AD_CODCANAL IN (1)
        AND   VEN1.CODVEND = VEN2.CODVEND ) -
        (SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),ISNULL(SUM((ITE1.QTDNEG*ITE1.VLRUNIT)-ITE1.VLRDESC-ITE1.VLRREPRED) ,0))
        FROM TGFCAB CAB1 (NOLOCK)
        LEFT JOIN TGFITE   ITE1 (NOLOCK) ON ITE1.NUNOTA=CAB1.NUNOTA 
        LEFT JOIN TGFVEN   VEN1 (NOLOCK) ON VEN1.CODVEND=CAB1.CODVEND
        LEFT JOIN TGFPRO   PRO1 (NOLOCK) ON PRO1.CODPROD = ITE1.CODPROD
        WHERE CAB1.TIPMOV = 'D'
        AND   CONVERT(DATE,CAB1.DTFATUR) BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2019-01-31'
        AND   ITE1.CODCFO IN (1202,1411,2202,2204,2411)
        AND   CAB1.STATUSNOTA = 'L'
        AND   PRO1.MARCA = 'SAMSUNG'
        AND   PRO1.CODGRUPOPROD = 1001001
        AND   VEN1.AD_CODCANAL IN (1)
        AND   VEN1.CODVEND = VEN2.CODVEND

         )) AS REALIZADO,

        (SELECT 
        SUM(MET.PREVREC) AS META_VN
        FROM TGMMET MET
        LEFT JOIN TGFVEN   VEN (NOLOCK) ON VEN.CODVEND = MET.CODVEND
        WHERE   MET.CODMETA = 6
        AND     VEN.AD_CODCANAL IN (1)
        AND    VEN.CODVEND = VEN2.CODVEND

        ) AS META


        FROM TGFVEN VEN2
        WHERE VEN2.AD_CODCANAL IN (1)--VN
        )A
```

O resultado desse select traz o resultado abaixo.
Na coluna apelido traz o nome das pessoas, grifei pois não faz sentido mostra-las.

Quero poder realizar o filtro pela coluna Ranking que é uma coluna calculada.
Por exemplo, gostaria de passar um Where/And nela, é possível?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi é isso que você precisa:

```html
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT TOP 5 A.APELIDO,
        A.REALIZADO,
        A.META,
        CAST((A.REALIZADO/A.META)*100 AS DECIMAL(10)) AS ACUMULADO,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ((A.REALIZADO/A.META)*100)DESC) AS RANKING

        FROM (

        SELECT

        VEN2.APELIDO,

        ((SELECT ISNULL(SUM((ITE1.QTDNEG*ITE1.VLRUNIT)-ITE1.VLRDESC-ITE1.VLRREPRED),0)
        FROM TGFCAB CAB1 (NOLOCK)
        LEFT JOIN TGFITE   ITE1 (NOLOCK) ON ITE1.NUNOTA=CAB1.NUNOTA 
        LEFT JOIN TGFVEN   VEN1 (NOLOCK) ON VEN1.CODVEND=CAB1.CODVEND
        LEFT JOIN TGFPRO   PRO1 (NOLOCK) ON PRO1.CODPROD = ITE1.CODPROD
        WHERE CAB1.TIPMOV = 'V'
        AND   CONVERT(DATE,CAB1.DTFATUR) BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2019-01-31'
        AND   ITE1.CODCFO IN (5102,5403,5405,5922,6102,6108,6110,6403,6404,6922)
        AND   CAB1.STATUSNFE <> 'D'
        AND   PRO1.MARCA = 'SAMSUNG'
        AND   PRO1.CODGRUPOPROD = 1001001
        AND   VEN1.AD_CODCANAL IN (1)
        AND   VEN1.CODVEND = VEN2.CODVEND ) -
        (SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),ISNULL(SUM((ITE1.QTDNEG*ITE1.VLRUNIT)-ITE1.VLRDESC-ITE1.VLRREPRED) ,0))
        FROM TGFCAB CAB1 (NOLOCK)
        LEFT JOIN TGFITE   ITE1 (NOLOCK) ON ITE1.NUNOTA=CAB1.NUNOTA 
        LEFT JOIN TGFVEN   VEN1 (NOLOCK) ON VEN1.CODVEND=CAB1.CODVEND
        LEFT JOIN TGFPRO   PRO1 (NOLOCK) ON PRO1.CODPROD = ITE1.CODPROD
        WHERE CAB1.TIPMOV = 'D'
        AND   CONVERT(DATE,CAB1.DTFATUR) BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2019-01-31'
        AND   ITE1.CODCFO IN (1202,1411,2202,2204,2411)
        AND   CAB1.STATUSNOTA = 'L'
        AND   PRO1.MARCA = 'SAMSUNG'
        AND   PRO1.CODGRUPOPROD = 1001001
        AND   VEN1.AD_CODCANAL IN (1)
        AND   VEN1.CODVEND = VEN2.CODVEND

         )) AS REALIZADO,

        (SELECT 
        SUM(MET.PREVREC) AS META_VN
        FROM TGMMET MET
        LEFT JOIN TGFVEN   VEN (NOLOCK) ON VEN.CODVEND = MET.CODVEND
        WHERE   MET.CODMETA = 6
        AND     VEN.AD_CODCANAL IN (1)
        AND    VEN.CODVEND = VEN2.CODVEND

        ) AS META


        FROM TGFVEN VEN2
        WHERE VEN2.AD_CODCANAL IN (1)--VN
        )A
) XX
WHERE XX.RANKING > 3
```